# Check parameter in Lambda Expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have this code:

```
 Function<Integer, String> converter = (num) -> Integer.toString(num);
```

As I see here the "num" is the parameter of the function, however, if my user accidentally input a float, there will be error.
I only create the "num" parameter in the Function code?
How can I add an exception like `if(!(num instanceOf Integer)) {//throw exception}`.

Comment: The `Integer` after `<` means it will not take a `float` (it would be a compile time error).

Comment: Your lambda should be `num -> num.toString()`.

Comment: @Andreas: there is an interesting difference. `num -> num.toString()` could work with non-`Integer` types, whereas `Integer.toString(num)` intrinsically requires `num` to be an `Integer`, even if it wasn’t mandated by the target type anyway. But since the target type enforce `num` to be an `Integer`, you could indeed use `num -> num.toString()` or even `Object::toString` and still get a function that doesn’t work with non-`Integer` input…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred one according [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) is checking its type before the `Function` calling.

```
if(input instanceof Integer){
    return converter.apply((Integer)input);
}else{
    //throw exception;
}
```

OR you need use `Optional` filtering the input.

```
Function<Integer, String> converter = (num) -> Integer.toString(num);

String result = Optional.ofNullable(input)
            .filter(Integer.class::isInstance)
            .map(Integer.class::cast)
            .map(converter).orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
```

OR you can combine `Optional` & `Function` to declaring two functions one is checking the type, another one is converter, but I think this is unnecessary and over coding in your situation.

```
Function<Object, Integer> typeChecking = (input) -> (Integer) Optional.ofNullable(input)
        .filter(Integer.class::isInstance)
        .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);

Function<Integer, String> intToString = (num) -> Integer.toString(num);

Function<Object, String> converter = typeChecking.andThen(intToString);
```

Checking parameter type in lambda expression will resulting in your lambda bloated,and usually unnecessary because you can't pass incompatible types to the lambda expression if you define your FunctionInterface with exactly parameter types,if you do like @Holger was given a CalssCastException will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

To add checks to a lambda expression just use it as if it was a function:

```
Function<Number , String> converter = (num) -> {
    final String result;
    if (num instanceof Integer) {
        result = Integer.toString((int)num);
    } else {
        result = "show some error";
       //Or throw an exception
    }
    return result;
};
```

A better way would be to call a method as this could get messy for longer methods.

Maybe somehting like this:

```
Function<Number , String> converter = e -> convertString(e);

public static String convertString(Number num) {
    final String result;
    if (num instanceof Integer) {
        result = Integer.toString((int)num);
    } else {
        result = "show some error";
    }
    return result;
}
```

You could also use  FooClass::convertString.

Comment: In both variants, it is impossible that `num` is not an `Integer`. That should be especially obvious in the second example, where you explicitly declare `Integer num`.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a compile time error as soon as you will try to pass the converter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function<Integer, String> converter = (num) -> Integer.toString(num);
        Stream<String> stream = asList(1, 3, 4.5).stream().map(converter); //compilation error here as soon as you enter a float in asList.
        stream.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Comment: Then how can I add an exception there? like if (num isntanceOf Integer) {// throw exception}, because I only create the "num" parameter in the Function code?

Comment: why do you need to throw an exception, when compiler is preventing it ? What is you actual requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper method that returns your converter Function wrapped in a try catch.

```
Function<Integer, String> converter = num -> num.toString();

System.out.println(wrapper(converter).apply(5));

private static Function<Integer, String> wrapper(Function<Integer, String> function) {
        return x -> {
            try {
                return function.apply(x);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "Error";
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration

```
Function<Integer, String> converter = num -> Integer.toString(num);
```

is just a short-hand for

```
Function<Integer, String> converter = (Integer num) -> Integer.toString(num);
```

letting the compiler infer the type of `num`, using the target type `Function<Integer, String>`. While `Function` is a generic interface whose type arguments could be ignored using an *unchecked* operation, the formal parameter of the lambda expression has the specified type which can’t be tainted. I.e.

```
((Function)converter).apply(1f); // should raise "unchecked" warning
```

will throw `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`, before even entering the code of your lambda expression.

It’s like you had written

```
Function<Integer, String> converter = MyClass::myLambdaCode;
…
private static String myLambdaCode(Integer num) {
    return Integer.toString(num);
}
```

just more concise. But technically, it’s the same. It is impossible to enter the code with an object that is not an instance of `Integer`. Checking whether `num` is something other than an `Integer` has no point. It always is (unless `null`). If it is `null`, a `NullPointerException` would be thrown by `Integer.toString(num)` anyway, so checking that beforehand, just to do the same, i.e. throw an exception, is obsolete.